# How to create node twig template suggestions for one content type?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes, hooks

I need to create a node twig template that is just for the `basic page` content type that based on a custom field on the content type. We have other content type like `Article`, `Blog`, `Products` that do not need these specific twig template.

**How would we create twig templates based on the `field_type` so that it only applies to the basic page content type?**

Here is what we tried, but couldn't find how we could detect for the `basic page` content type and the value for the `field_type`. We tried `ksm($suggestions)` and `ksm($variables)`, but it does not print which implies that the hook isn't called even after clearing cache.

```
function mymodule_theme_suggestions_node_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // This is what we are looking for. 
  $node_bundle = $node->bundle();
  if($node_bundle == 'page') {
    // we want something like this.
    $node_type_value = $node->field_type->value;
    $node_view_mode = $node->view_mode; // not sure what this would be. 
    $suggestions[] = 'node__' . $node_bundle . '__' . $node_type_value
  }
}
```

Comment: Where have you defined `$node` (if you haven’t, it’s in `$variables[‘node’]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the values first you want to work with. For example the node object is inside `$variables['elements']['#node']`. In the sample below `field_foobar` is a text field. Depending on what your field type is you may need to get the value you want a little bit differently. And also maybe sanitize it first before you use it in a template suggestion (replace spaces etc.).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_node_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node */
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
  if ($node->bundle() === 'page') {
    if (!$node->get('field_foobar')->isEmpty()) {
      $value = $node->get('field_foobar')->first()->getValue()['value'];
      $view_mode = $variables['elements']['#view_mode'];
      $suggestions[] = 'node__page__' . $view_mode . '__' . $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: getting the `$node` from `$variables['elements']['#node'];` got me exactly what i needed.